# Slow xamarin build in visual studio 2017

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017, parallels

I am of recently developing a `Xamarin` based app in `Visual Studio 2017` and I am not sure whether the performance I see at a build and debug time is what can be expected or if something is wrong.

Environment: imac late 2015, quad core i5 @3.5GHz, 24GB RAM.
I am executing visual studio (latest) under parallels 13 in windows 10 and have assigned all four cores and 20GB RAM to the VM (it doesn't make a difference though if I assign less).

The solution is a standard xamarin based solution with 3 projects and about 10 classes with roughly 300loc (yes really, there's almost nothing in there yet).
A rebuild takes about 1 Minute. Starting the application in debug mode takes about 30s for the simulator showing up.
Looking at the code size and hardware specs I was expecting build and simulation to be a matter of seconds.
Am I wrong? Even considering the VM I'd not have expected these numbers.
Is anybody able to share experiences/thoughts?

Comment: Yes, building Xamarin projects is rather slow.

Comment: In general Xamarin is slower than Xcode or Android Studio build times... VisualStudio/Xamarin is highly dependent upon disk IO, the best way to determine what is causing the slow builds is to enable diagnostic level MSBuild logging and review the execution time summary at the end of the build. Also you should not close the Android emulator/iOS simulator between debug runs, also if using an Android emulator, it is faster to run it in the host and have the VM guest connect to it vs running it within the guest itself.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem isn't simply compile time. Every time you build your project, your shared code gets compiled into a dll, code dependencies get checked, then linked into the native project, which is being compiled, resources get packed, integrity-checked and signed and is finally being bundled (not speaking of included nuget Packages and other plugins) and then the whole package gets packed into an app archive, which also needs time to be written.

Also your app gets transmitted to your device via USB or network (default would be USB).

Considering what is happening "under the hood", 30 seconds is quite fast.

However, I have found that the performance is less based upon cpu and ram (at least if your dev machine has a decent amount of both) but on the performance of your hard disk.

If you really want to speed things up, you might consider running visual studio and doing your compiling on a nvme drive (an alternative might be a SSD raid).

For instance I once had a xamarin app, which had a lot of dependencies on various nuget packages. Compiling the iOS Version took about 25 minutes (full rebuild) on a Mac Mini (2011 model improved with an aftermarket Samsung 850 Pro), switching to a VM solution running on a skull canyon NUC equipped with a Samsung 950 Pro nvme drive did speed up the process to incredible 2.5 minutes.

Comment: Do you think moving the VM to a USB 3 connected SSD would improve build significantly? Because that would be an affordable option...

Comment: I don't think so. Your USB 3.0 SSD would have an effective bandwidth of 300 Mb/s.

It might be worth taking a shot using a USB 3.1 drive, which would allow a bandwidth of 900 Mb/s.

However, using a SSD limits you to ~ 500 MB/s, so in order to reach those 900 MB/s you'd need a USB connected nvme drive.

If you have to use a SSD, you'd be better off installing the SSD internally given you have a SATA III port available in your pc, since that USB connection is most likely to become a bottleneck.

Comment: When you say "switching to a VM solution running on a skull canyon NUC equipped with a Samsung 950 Pro" do you mean macOS running in a VM?